# Unable to fetch the values from drop down in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I am not able to select the values which are in state drop down list,while selecting the country drop down list State Should be selected but state drop down is not able to select the values.

```
    Select dropdown28 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("intEmpDepCountry")));
    dropdown28.selectByIndex(2);

    Select dropdown29 = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ddlstate']")));
    dropdown29.selectByIndex(2);
```

How i can Solve this issue??

Comment: Please look for any frames / iframe present or try to increase wait time...

Answer (score 0):

Please write code in below way to solve your issue :

```
    Select dropdown28 = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("intEmpDepCountry")));
    dropdown28.selectByVisibleText("yourdropdowntext");
```

I think your code having problem to finding value by index. Also I request you to set wait period after find country value. Because if you are loading states based on country selection then it always takes minor time to load states once country selected.

To set wait , you can use code :

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Comment: thanks for your replay.In the Country drop down  value is fetching But i don't no y state drop down is not able to fetch as per the country drop down.

Comment: Please try to put some wait by Thread.sleep(5000) for testing purpose or wait till all options are loaded for state when selecting particular country and then try to select your state.

Comment: yes i kept wait.driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(35, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

Comment: then now what is going there? Do you getting any specific error?